# Loading Bitmap Failed on Berlin

Tags: delphi, bitmap, firemonkey, datasnap, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a problem migrating a process from XE8 to Berlin 10.1.

On XE8, it works fine.

On Berlin, I get a "Loading Bitmap Failed" error.

I have a DataSnap REST server with this method:

```
function TSM.Downloafile(): TStream;
var
  s: TFileStream;
begin
  s := TFileStream.Create('C:\image1.jpg', fmOpenReadWrite);
  Result := s;
end;
```

On XE8, I get the stream fine, I can see the image using a URL in a browser, like:

> http://localhost:105/datasnap/rest/TSM/Downloafile

On Berlin, when I try to show the image, I get this string instead:

> [122,216,255,244,0,15,......]

And then loading of the Bitmap fails.

Comment: As just a side note, there's no reason to use `fmOpenReadWrite` if you don't intend to write. In some environments, this could even fail if you don't have write privileges to the given folder.

Comment: Also, I doubt this is related to Firemonkey, considering you're talking about a REST Server accessed from a Browser. I suggest change your question to be focused on the fact that your REST server is returning an unexpected format.

Comment: As far as your actual problem, we cannot see enough relevant code. Where do you handle the request/response? What do you pass for `ContentType`?

Comment: Further aside, no point of the local variable s, assign directly to Result

Comment: I have not set ContentType as i said on XE8 work fine i can see the image, the problem is on Berlin, the stream return a string like [122,216,255,244,0,15,......] and fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved this case using ?json=false in the URL, thanks

Answer (score -1):

when you say DataSnap REST server i guess then the TSM.Downloafile(): TStream; is not call from the main thread. bitmap are not multithread and must be use only from the main thread

Comment: this code work fine on XE8, the problem is on Berlin that return a string like [122,216,255,244,0,15,......] and fail